# Handle XML data that is in single quote while loading

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can anybody tell me how to load below data into database.

```
declare @learnxml varchar(5000);set @learnxml = '<alerts><alert id="i-20200107-1"><alertTime>2020-01-07T00:13:07.000-0500</alertTime><text>See the attached CSV for details (Click 'Export Attachment' at the top of the screen).</text> <state> <alertStatus>New</alertStatus> <alertAssignee/> </state> <alertCount>1</alertCount> <startTime>2020-01-07T00:13:07.000-0500</startTime> </alert> </alerts>';DECLARE @fileDataX XML = @learnxml PRINT @learnxml;SELECT  xData.value('../@id','Varchar(100)') AlertId,
xData.value('../alertTime[1]','VARCHAR(50)') AlertTime,
xData.value('../text[1]','varchar(max)') AlertText,
xData.value('../alertCount[1]','int') AlertCount,
xData.value('../startTime[1]','VARCHAR(50)') AlertStartTime,
xData.value('(.)/alertStatus[1]', 'varchar(100)') AlertStatus,
xData.value('(.)/alertAssignee[1]', 'varchar(100)') AlertAssignee   FROM @fileDataX.nodes('./alerts/alert/state') as x(xData)
```

Above query gives me an error

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
>   Incorrect syntax near 'Export'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A literal string in TSQL is enclosed in single quote characters: '.  Any single quotes that need to appear in the string must be escaped by using two consecutive single quote characters: ''

So

```
declare @learnxml varchar(5000);
set @learnxml = '<alerts><alert id="i-20200107-1"><alertTime>2020-01-07T00:13:07.000-0500</alertTime><text>See the attached CSV for details (Click ''Export Attachment'' at the top of the screen).</text> <state> <alertStatus>New</alertStatus> <alertAssignee/> </state> <alertCount>1</alertCount> <startTime>2020-01-07T00:13:07.000-0500</startTime> </alert> </alerts>';
DECLARE @fileDataX XML = @learnxml 
PRINT @learnxml;
SELECT  
    xData.value('../@id','Varchar(100)') AlertId,
    xData.value('../alertTime[1]','VARCHAR(50)') AlertTime,
    xData.value('../text[1]','varchar(max)') AlertText,
    xData.value('../alertCount[1]','int') AlertCount,
    xData.value('../startTime[1]','VARCHAR(50)') AlertStartTime,
    xData.value('(.)/alertStatus[1]', 'varchar(100)') AlertStatus,
    xData.value('(.)/alertAssignee[1]', 'varchar(100)') AlertAssignee   
FROM @fileDataX.nodes('./alerts/alert/state') as x(xData)
```

Comment: Browne I can't change the XML file as it is coming from another system.I have to load as it is..Is there a way I can do this?

Comment: That doesn't change the XML.  The TSQL code that you used to test had a bug in how the string literal is created.

Comment: That's what I am saying..I did not create this XML file..This is how I got this XML file.

Comment: You can't just paste XML between single-quote characters and end up with a valid TSQL literal.  The single-quote character is allowed in XML element text, but must be escaped in a TSQL string literal.